# Change Tick Values in RadialAxisPlot

Tags: plotting

I am simply trying to change the tick labels on my RadialAxisPlot and the FrameTicks function does not seem to work. I'd simply like to change the axes ticks to reduce the number of ticks and relabel them if necessary.

The input code is three attempts:

```
data = RandomInteger[10, {4, 3}];

RadialAxisPlot[data, PlotRange -> {1 -> {0, 15}, _ -> {0, 10}}]
RadialAxisPlot[data, PlotRange -> {1 -> {0, 7, 15}, _ -> {0, 2, 10}}]
RadialAxisPlot[data, PlotRange -> {1 -> {0, 15}, _ -> {0, 10}}, 
 FrameTicks -> {1 -> {0, 7, 15}, _ -> {0, 2, 8, 10}}]
```

[image: Plot 1]

[image: Plot 2]

[image: Plot 3]

Comment: The code you posted is incomplete and does not run.  Please provide a complete example of y9our problem, including `data`..

Answer (score 3):

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = RandomInteger[10, {4, 3}];
n = Last @ Dimensions[data];
```

Looks like `RadialAxisPlot` does not allow user specified ticks.

***A work-around:*** Construct the axes with desired ticks using [`AxisObject`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AxisObject.html):

```
ticks = {{0, 7, 15}, { 2, 8, 10}, { 2, 8, 10}};

axes = MapThread[AxisObject[Line[{{0, 0}, #}], {0, #2}, 
     TickPositions -> {{#3}, {0, #2, 1}}, 
     TickLengths -> {.02, .01}] &, 
   {CirclePoints[{1, Pi/2}, n], {15, 10, 10}, ticks}];
```

Use the option `Axes -> False` and add `axes` as the setting for `Epilog`:

```
RadialAxisPlot[data, PlotRange -> {1 -> {0, 15}, _ -> {0, 10}}, 
 Axes -> False, ImageSize -> Large, Epilog -> axes]
```

[image]